# Executing a command in the command prompt using c# for a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm currently building a WPF application. I want to be able to choose a binary file, decode it using the command prompt command line arguments into a .csv file, edit its value in my application then decode it back to a binary file using a decoding tool.The only part where I'm stuck at is entering my commandline arguments into the command prompt. I googled stuff, but I could only find information on how to open the command prompt from code and not how to execute a command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of dupes on SO for: How do I execute a command on the shell in C#?  WPF doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 5):

checkout Process class, it is part of the .NET framework - for more information and some sample code see [its documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

EDIT - as per comment:

sample code that start 7zip and reads StdOut

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = @"C:\7za.exe"; // Specify exe name.
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

some links to samples:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369/en-us
- [c# ProcessStartInfo.Start - reading output but with a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718473/c-processstartinfo-start-reading-output-but-with-a-timeout/5718577#5718577)
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start
- http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/02/06/invoking-cmd-exe-from-net.aspx
- http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/run-console-app-without-dos-box.htm
- http://dfcowell.net/2011/01/printing-a-pdf-in-c-net-adobe-reader/