# SNMPWalk Error in C# Process init

Tags: c#, snmp

I'm creating an application at work that uses SNMPWalk to get details on specific IP addresses. Right now it's meant to use Nmap to find all printers in a specified network and then it uses SNMPWalk to get details on each printer.

The problem is that SNMPWalk is giving me the error:

```
"No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
-v2c:  (Sub-id not found: (top) -> -v2c)"
```

My code is here:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = snmploc + "\\snmpwalk.exe";

p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = snmploc;

p.StartInfo.Arguments = "–mALL -v2c –cpublic " + printer.IP();

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Snmpwalk has been fired");

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Snmp to terminate...");

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(p.ExitCode);
```

`printer` is an object of the class `Printer`. It is used to contain printer details such as ip address, name, model, serial number, and open ports. `snmploc` is obtained from command line arguments.

The main reason that this is so complicated is that when I try using the exact same command in a command prompt it works perfectly.

Comment: I changed up the order of the arguments and capitalized the V. It now reads `"-V2c –cpublic -mAll " + printer.IP();`
`output` is now "" and `error` is `"NET-SNMP version: 5.6.1.1\r\n"` `ExitCode` has a value of 0.
I hope this helps people in finding a solution!

Comment: I found the solution! `p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v2c -cpublic -mAll " + printer.IP();` is the way to go. Also, use the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718473/c-sharp-processstartinfo-start-reading-output-but-with-a-timeout) to redirect the output.

Comment: You ought to write the answer as an answer, at least to prevent others from wasting time trying to solve it!