# How to execute perl script with input parameters and output the result to a file in C#

Tags: c#, perl

I want to execute a perl script in my c# code and output the result to a file.  The perl script will take in a binary file name as an input parameter, and I want to redirect the  result to a text file.  I have the following in my c# code, but the output file test.txt is not created.  Please advise if you know the problem:

```
private Process myProcess = null;

myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "perl.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\mydir\\myPerl.pl C:\\mydir\\myFile.DAT > C:\\mydir\\test.txt";
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the Perl script runs and works correctly?  If so, I suspect that this is really a C# issue.  Otherwise I'd validate that the Perl script is correct first.

Comment: The perl script is correct because if I execute it using the command line, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've answer a similar question [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718473/c-processstartinfo-start-reading-output-but-with-a-timeout/5718577#5718577) of [times before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693191/c-run-several-external-executables/5695109#5695109):

Here's my previous answer. Just replace the delegates to write to a file instead.

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Myexe.exe");
processInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process proc = Process.Start(processInfo);

// You can pass any delegate that matches the appropriate 
// signature to ErrorDataReceived and OutputDataReceived
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, errorLine) => { if (errorLine.Data != null) Trace.WriteLine(errorLine.Data); };
proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, outputLine) => { if (outputLine.Data != null) Trace.WriteLine(outputLine.Data); };
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

proc.WaitForExit();
```

In your particular case, don't forget to remove the "`> C:\\mydir\\test.txt`" from your command line.

Answer (score 0):

Does the program execute? I mean is it just that the output file doesn't get created or the process is not starting? By the way, you will need to escape those backslashes or use @ before the argument string.

The redirection is not an argument, so I don't think you can specify "> C:\mydir\test.txt"" in the arguments parameter. Try using [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) for this instead. Or you can also try taking in the output file as an argument in the perl script and make the perl code write the text file.

Comment: Yes, the program execute without any problem, but the output is not created.

Comment: Tried Process.StandardOutput (see the examples on the page, you need to set  Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false and Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true before using it.)